# Return an array that is randomly filled with string variables

Tags: javascript

We have three string variables and we want a function to return an array that is randomly filled with those variables.

The desired result should be something like this:

```
['first string', 'third string', 'second string']; // each variable as a single element
```

```js
function generateArray(){

    let a = 'first string';
    let b = 'second string';
    let c = 'third string';
    
    let ourArray = [];
    
    // return ourArray randomly filled with 'a' 'b' and 'c'
    
}
```

Comment: Use [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to put all your variables into an array then shuffles (randomly reorders) elements of that array:

```
  function generateArray(){

        function shuffle(array) {
            return array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
        }

        let a = 'first string';
        let b = 'second string';
        let c = 'third string';

        var localArray = new Array(a, b, c); 
        return shuffle(localArray);  

    }
```